# Pandas rounding decimals not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, rounding

Can someone please explain what's happening me or am I missing something really obvious?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0094909865]])
df = df.round(9)
print(df)
```

This gives me **0.009490986**.

I was expecting a rounded value of **0.009490987**

Can someone help me understand? 
I am using Pandas '0.20.3'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. This is an undocumented quirk. Actually, `DataFrame.round` uses `numpy.around`. It should be mentioned in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html).

---

The `numpy.around()` does the following:

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, Numpy
>   rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5
>   and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.

See the [Reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) for more details.

### To achieve what you want you can do the following:

```
from math import ceil, floor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0094909865]])

def float_round(num, places = 0, direction = floor):
    return direction(num * (10**places)) / float(10**places)

print( float_round(df.values,9,ceil) )
print( float_round(df.values,9) )

print( float_round(1.1389182804 ,9) )
```

### Results

```
0.009490987
0.009490986

1.13891828
```

Comment: Thank you @seralouk, that at least helps with me getting my sanity back! I was struggling the whole evening thinking I am missing something fairly obvious, but am glad it wasn't me.

Comment: any idea how I can achieve what I am setting about to do - plain rounding like excel does? Thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant, much appreciated.

Comment: when I attempt to use your function on value 1.1389182804, it gives me 1.138918281 instead of 1.138918280 when i round to 9 decimals?

Comment: use this: float_round(1.1389182804 ,9)

Comment: This is part of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) actually, I wouldn't suggest going against the standard.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just suggested a way to get what @Gayathri needs.

Comment: Why is this a quirk? It is the mathematical definition of rounding and implemented in Python round() as well. That MS Excel is unaware of mathematics (just try their stats functions) is not Python's problem.

Comment: I just said that the fact that pandas round uses numpy around is a undocumented quirk. It should be clearly mentioned in pandas documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Comment: The documentation clause you quote isn't strictly relevant here, because the value you're testing is _not_ "exactly halfway between rounded decimal values". The actual value being stored is `0.009490986499999999603804923253846936859190464019775390625`, which is *closer* to `0.009490986` than to `0.009490987`. Having said that, the method used internally by NumPy also potentially introduces intermediate errors. In practice, it's hard to predict reliably which way _apparent_ halfway cases will actually round.