# Round function to avoid error caused by null data

Tags: pandas

**data**

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/titanic.csv

**Goal**

- round data by my defined function like below.

**Problem**

- When `df.age.map(float_round)`, it returns `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`.

I don't want to split data into null data and changed the not null data and then merge it. But using one function to achieve it.

```
from math import ceil, floor


def float_round(num, places=2, direction = ceil):
    return direction(num * (10**places)) / float(10**places)
```

Note: the round function could not achieve what I want. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320813/pandas-rounding-decimals-not-working/50320846#50320846) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix would be to use [`np.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html#numpy-ceil)/[`np.floor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html#numpy-floor) which are both `NaN` safe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import ceil, floor


def float_round(num, places=2, direction=ceil):
    return direction(num * (10 ** places)) / float(10 ** places)


df = pd.read_csv('./data/titanic.csv')
df['age'] = df['age'].map(float_round)
```

```
df.tail(5)[['survived', 'pclass', 'sex', 'age']]
```

```
     survived  pclass     sex   age
886         0       2    male  27.0
887         1       1  female  19.0
888         0       3  female   NaN  # Still NaN no errors
889         1       1    male  26.0
890         0       3    male  32.0
```

---

Otherwise check if [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy-isnan) before trying to call `math.ceil` or `math.floor`:

```
from math import ceil, floor

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def float_round(num, places=2, direction=ceil):
    if not np.isnan(num):
        return direction(num * (10 ** places)) / float(10 ** places)
    else:
        return np.NaN
```