# How to using define round function like pandas round that executing one line code

Tags: pandas

**Goal**

- Only one line to execute.
- I refer round function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68051735/5576930). But I want using like `df.round(2)` which changes the affected columns but keep the sequence of data but not required selecting float or int type.
- df.applymap(myfunction) will get `TypeError: must be real number, not str`, which means I have to select type first.

**Try**

- I refer [round source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L8211-L8320) but I could not and understand how to change my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly get the columns where values are float:

```
cols=df.select_dtypes('float').columns
```

Finally:

```
df[cols]=df[cols].agg(round,ndigits=2)
```

If you want to make changes in the function then add if/else condition:

```
from numpy import ceil, floor


def float_round(num, places=2, direction=ceil):
    if isinstance(num,float):
        return direction(num * (10 ** places)) / float(10 ** places)
    else:
        return num

out=df.applymap(float_round)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the error message you mention, it's likely the column is already a string, and needs to be converted to some numeric type.

Let's now assume that the column is numeric, there are a few ways you could implement custom rounding functions that don't require reimplementing the `.round()` method of a dataframe object.

With the requirements you laid above, we want a way to round a data frame that:

- fits on one line
- doesn't require selecting numeric type

There are two ways we could do this that are functionally equivalent. One is to treat the dataframe as an argument to a function that is safe for numpy arrays.

Another is to use the apply method (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)) which applies a function to a row or a column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from numpy import ceil

# generate a 100x10 dataframe with a null value
data = np.random.random(1000) * 10
data = data.reshape(100,10)
data[0, 0] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# changing data type of the second column
df[1] = df[1].astype(int)

# verify dtypes are different
print(df.dtypes)

# taken from other stack post
def float_round(num, places=2, direction=ceil):
    return direction(num * (10 ** places)) / float(10 ** places)

# method 1 - use the dataframe as an argument
result1 = float_round(df)
print(result1.head())

# method 2 - apply 
result2 = df.apply(float_round)
print(result2)
```

Because apply is applied row or column-wise, you can specify logic in your round function to ignore non-numeric columns. For instance:

```
# taken from other stack post
def float_round(num, places=2, direction=ceil):
    # check type of a specific column
    if num.dtype == 'O':
        return num
    return direction(num * (10 ** places)) / float(10 ** places)

# this will work, method 1 will fail
result2 = df.apply(float_round)
print(result2)
```

Comment: If type contains not only string but datetime etc. It will failed. I think Anurag Dabas's answer can avoid the problem.